# cant use Activerecord find method with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

here are my models:

```
#game 
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relationships with the teams for a given game
  belongs_to :team_1,:class_name=>"Team",:foreign_key=>"team_1_id"
  belongs_to :team_2,:class_name=>"Team",:foreign_key=>"team_2_id"

  def self.find_games(name)
  items = Game.find(:all,:include=>[:team_1,:team_2] , :conditions => ["team_1.name = ?", name] )     
  end
end

#teams
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relationships with games
  has_many :games, :foreign_key  =>'team_1'
  has_many :games, :foreign_key  =>'team_2'
end
```

When i execute Game.find_games("real") i get :
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: team_1.name

How can i fix the problem i thought that using :include would fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Team_1 is not the name of the table.  The conditions don't work with associations as defined in ruby, but with the tables themselves.  The condition should state: `:conditions => ["teams.name = ?", name]`

Also, I don't think the teams class is correct, you certainly can't define games twice, and the foreign keys should be the same as the belongs to:

```
#teams
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  #relationships with games
  has_many :team_1_games, :class_name => "Game", :foreign_key  =>'team_1_id'
  has_many :team_2_games, :class_name => "Game", :foreign_key  =>'team_2_id'
end
```

There is a much better way to do that, but I can't remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: i tried it  its working however it look for a name only in team_1.i want it to look for both attribute team_1 and team_2.